# "@@" in Flatpak desktop files

Tags: .desktop, flatpak

In the `Exec` lines of desktop files exported by Flatpak, the field code for the file/URL to be passed to the application is surrounded by `@@`:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=blender --file-forwarding org.blender.Blender @@ %f @@
```

What does this mean? The [spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.htm) doesn't mention it and the desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` don't contain it either.

Answer (score 5):

> #### --file-forwarding
>
> If this option is specified, the remaining arguments are scanned, and all arguments that are enclosed between a pair of '@@' arguments are interpreted as file paths, exported in the document store, and passed to the command in the form of the resulting document path. Arguments between '@@u' and '@@' are considered uris, and any file: uris are exported. The exports are non-persistent and with read and write permissions for the application.

[flatpak-run (1)](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-run)